Mask clusters larger than 500 pixels in GEE ends with a memory error
The function below, getLargeIIFF, is designed in GEE to identify and classify large clusters of connected pixels in a given image with only one band (IMG) as a specific class (5).
It uses an 8-way connectivity kernel (9x9 square) to label clusters of connected pixels in the image. Each cluster gets a unique label. It computes the size of each labeled cluster by counting the number of connected pixels in each cluster. It identifies clusters larger than 500 pixels and updates their pixel values to 5 in the original image.
The function works when I use an image previously saved as an asset. However, when I use an image saved as a variable in memory, it fails due to

Error: Execution failed; out of memory (Error code: 8).

Is there a way to process it to avoid the memory error?
function getLargeIIFF(img) {
  // Step 1: Label connected components with 8-way connectivity (9x9 kernel)
  var kernel = ee.Kernel.square(3);  // Define kernel once for reusability
  var connectedComponents = img.connectedComponents(kernel, 555);

  // Step 2: Compute cluster sizes
  var clusterSize = connectedComponents.select('labels').connectedPixelCount(555, true);

  // Step 3: Mask clusters larger than 500 pixels and classify them as 5
  return img.where(clusterSize.gt(500), 5);
}

exports = {
  getLargeIIFF: getLargeIIFF
};

Apart from the function, this is the full workflow; Step 4 is the one that fails:
// Load required modules
var ccd = require('users/user/ccdc:202_Procesos_clasificacion_LS/get_vp_ccd_ls.js');
var utils = require('users/user/Funciones_RS:utils/api');

// Configuration and input
var prov = 'Castellon';
var provincias = configFile_v2;
var saveRegion = provincias.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAMEUNIT', prov));

// Generate input data
var input_pv_for_class = ccd.run_ccdc_by_prov(saveRegion, prov, '2022-01-01', '2022-12-31');

// Classification model
var model_path = 'users/user/ccdc/class/models/';
var model_name = 'model_sev_v2';
var saveClassifier = ee.Classifier.load(model_path + model_name);

// Important variables for classification
var impVars = ['NBR_MAG', 'NBR_SIN', 'NBR_SIN2', 'NBR_COS', 'NBR_COS2','NBR_COS3', 'NBR_RMSE', 'NBR_INTP', 'NBR_SLP', 'NBR_SIN3'];
var inputClass = input_pv_for_class.select(impVars);

// Classification
var classified = inputClass.classify(saveClassifier).toInt8();

// Step 1: Apply Focal Mode Filter
function applyFocalMode(img, kernelSize) {
    var nonZeroMask = img.neq(0); // Mask for non-zero pixels
    var filtered = img.updateMask(nonZeroMask).focalMode(kernelSize, 'square', 'pixels', 1);
    return filtered.updateMask(nonZeroMask).unmask(img); // Retain original zeros
}

var classifiedModeFiltered = applyFocalMode(classified, 3); // 7x7 pixels

// Step 2: Apply Sieve
function applySieve(img, minPixels) {
    var binary = img.where(img.gt(0), 1); // Convert classes > 0 to binary
    var count = binary.connectedPixelCount(minPixels); // Count connected pixels
    return img.updateMask(count.gte(minPixels)); // Mask small clusters
}

var classified_sieve = applySieve(classifiedModeFiltered, 3);

// Step 3: Increment Classes for Masked Areas
var mask = classified_sieve.gt(0).selfMask().toInt8();
var classified_final = classified_sieve.unmask(0).where(mask.eq(1), classified_sieve.add(1));

// Step 4: Identify Large Fires
// Pass the mask raster to getLargeIIFF
var largeFires = utils.GetIncendios.getLargeIIFF(mask);

// Step 5: Combine using simplified logic
var combined = classified_final.where(largeFires.eq(5), largeFires);

//// Export result sin identificación de incendios
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: combined.clip(saveRegion),
    //description: 'chg_final_output_' + prov + '_2022_con_iiff_' + model_name,
    description: 'combined',
    folder: 'ccdc',
    region: saveRegion,
    scale: 30,
    crs: 'EPSG:25830',
    maxPixels: 1e13
});


There isn't much you can do to optimize memory usage in the code you provide. There might be something to do with the image you provide as input though, but you didn't share that code. The most straight forward solution is to do what you already figured out - export the image as an asset before executing the function.

@DanielWiell, I have updated the post to show how I handle the input image. I used the reduce resolution function, but I doubt this is working as I expected. I am trying to avoid creating intermediate data as an asset.

Still, there is not enough of the image processing code to judge if this could work without exporting. In general, in EE, you should avoid fiddling with the projection and resolution, unless you know you really do need to. Drop reduceResolution() and see if it works.

Thanks, @DanielWiell; I have removed the reduceResolution() but it still fails due to memory. I also updated the post with the complete workflow; let's see if this gives more information.

Any time you're using a kernel or a neighborhood, you're going to be scale limited.  A kernel implicitly specifies a neighborhood and neighborhoods propagate all the way down to the inputs.  So if you specify a neighborhood of 300 pixels, that means each input tile actually needs to 25 neighboring tiles in order to be processed (tiles are 256x256, so a pixel 300 pixels away from the edge of a tile needs two more tiles in that direction).
And... neighborhoods compound, so if you use a 300 pixel neighborhood on top of something already using a 300 pixel neighborhood, you're actually asking for a 600 pixel neighborhood from each inmput.  And so on...
For things involving large neighborhoods (and especially for large regions), some other options are:

Try using fastDistanceTransform for erosion/dilation to get rid of small regions.  You can often do this in a single pass, and can avoid compounding neighborhoods.
Try using reduceToVectors to identify the really large patches.  (But this will only work if you only have a relatively small number of objects; less than 1M)

But honestly, if you've already made it work with an export, maybe you don't need to worry about additional efficiency.
